# Trying to build an error function

Tags: functions

The error function will work approximately like this:

```
0 <= error <= infinity
```

Most likely the error will be around 0 - 10,0000

```
0 <= score <= 1
```

Where score = 1 means the error is 0
and score ==> 0 means error >> 10,000.

Here are a few examples:

If error is between 0 to 10
The score should be between 1.0 to 0.95

Error = 0.5 then score = 0.99* Something like that..

If error is between 11 to 100
Score should be from 0.95 to 0.7

If score is from 101 to 1000
Score should be from 0.7 to 0.4

And if score is from 1001 till infinity score should move from 0.4 to 0.

Now, I don't want a step function, but something that is similar to the above description
Preferably a function that is continues...

Comment: This will be clearer if you [edit] the question to list the requirements in a table rather than with words. It's hard to keep "error" and "score" apart in your prose. The last sentence in the first paragraph makes no sense as written.

Comment: If error is from 101 to 1000?....If error is from 1001 till infinity?...Looks roughly like $Score = 1-\frac{log_{10}(1+10*error)}{10}$, something like that..

Comment: This is close Paul..
2 things that disturb me is that for error = 1, the score is already 0.9 and degregating.
And when the error is 10K, the score does not diminish fast enough, and it stays in the 0.5 area... I also suspect its something with log